# What are the Real #'s and Imaginary?

Tags: trigonometry

$5e^{-i(7\pi/6)}$

I figured $5e$ was real and $-(7\pi/6)$ was imaginary. I was wrong. Anyone have any thoughts as to what is real / imaginary in the complex number?? Thanks for any responses!

Comment: If a complex number is written in the form $a+bi$, then $a$ is the real part and $b$ is the imaginary part. Unfortunately, $"\!5e^{-i7\pi/6}\!"$ isn't in the form $a+bi$.

Comment: so how do you separate what is real and imaginary??

Comment: Do you know Euler's formula for $e^{i\theta}$?

Comment: Well it isn't given on the module i am using so i figured to answer the question you didn't need to know it.

Comment: However; at the end it states Your answers should be decimals with 2 digits to the right of the decimal point? Question A: The real part of this complex number is ____ and Question B: The Imaginary part of this number is _____

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger You still need $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Vim Yes, that's true. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Euler's formula says:
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$
Thus:
\begin{align}
5e^{-i7\pi/6}&=5\left(\cos\left(-\frac{7\pi}6\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac{7\pi}6\right)\right)\\
&=5\cos\left(-\frac{7\pi}6\right)+i5\sin\left(-\frac{7\pi}6\right)
\end{align}
You can simplify that.

Comment: Ok I see that; however, I am asked what the real part / imaginary parts are and told that they should be decimals with 2 digits to the right of the decimal point. (submitted 2ce and on 3rd submission = wrong so I wanna be sure of final answer)

Answer (score 0):

A:) The Real Part of this number is -4.33
B:) The Imaginary part of this number is 2.5
(The module stated these as the correct answers)

Comment: This is worthless without an explanation.